# StreamCorruptedException with ObjectInputStream and ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, java-io

I have a number of objects written to disk using ObjectOutputStream. During reading, I firstly retrieve the file as a ByteArray for some implementation reasons, I want to read the buffered array and decode the data from it. Here is a code snippet

```
byte [] fileArray=org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(filePath);

ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileArray));

while(true){
 Records pos=(Records)in.readObject();
}
```

However, I get this error

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 2F6C6F63
```

In summary, I want to load the file into memory and then decode the objects rather than from disk while reading.

---

The file is written as:

```
fout=new FileOutputStream(filePath);
bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
oos=new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
 oos.writeObject(list.get(i));
}
oos.flush();
bos.writeTo(fout);
bos=null;
oos=null;
fout.flush();
fout.close();
```

oos is not closed at all!

---

Here is a full example to reproduce the error:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.*;

public class Example{

    private int[] data;

    public Example(){
        data=new int[40];
    }

    public void generate(){
        for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            data[i]=i;
        }
        System.out.println("Data generated!");
    }

    public void write(){
        FileOutputStream fout=null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos=null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos=null;
        try{
            fout=new FileOutputStream("obj.data");
            bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            oos=new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                oos.writeObject((Integer)data[i]);
            }
            oos.flush();
            bos.writeTo(fout);
            bos=null;
            oos=null;
            fout.flush();
            fout.close();
        }catch(IOException ioe){}
        System.out.println("Data written!");
    }

    public void read(){
        ObjectInputStream in=null;
        try{
            byte[] fileArray=org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray("obj.data");
            in=new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileArray));
            while(true){
                Integer data=(Integer)in.readObject();
            }
        }catch (EOFException eofe){
            try{
                in.close();
            }catch (IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        System.out.println("Data read!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Example example=new Example();
        example.generate();
        example.write();
        example.read();
    }


}
```

Comment: Well, it sounds like the data is broken. What does the code writing it look like?

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for replying. Updated the question! I think that is the error but is there a way to fix by not going to data generation again!

Comment: Well let's diagnose the issue first... Can you reproduce this in a short but *complete* example, doing both the reading and writing, but showing the same error?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. Updated and it shows the same error

Comment: Why all the byte array streams? Just do the I/O directly to & from the file, and save yourself a lot of memory. Simpler code, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, found it now. This is the problem:

```
byte[] fileArray=org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray("obj.data");
```

[That method](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.lang.String%29) doesn't do what you think it does:

> Get the contents of a String as a byte[] using the default character encoding of the platform.

It's not loading a *file* at all.

If you use this instead:

```
 byte[] fileArray = 
     org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File("obj.data"));
```

... then the data is recovered correctly.

(Personally I prefer [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) for this sort of thing, by the way...)

Comment: Thank you Jon. That worked for me. Thanks for the link to Guava too.